# Can a single column header be empty or hidden in Tabulator

Tags: hide, tabulator, dynamic-columns

I have a HTML table, that I transform into a Tabulator table. It has four colums where column 1 and 4 do not have a headertext
[image: original table]

In Tabulator it is possible to hide the column headers as follows, with the **headerVisible** option:

[image: headerVisible:false]

I want to be able to hide the header of a single column. but it seems this option is not available. Below is what I want (edited via the DOM)

[image: example of what I am looking for]

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the column header to have a title, you should simply not set the title in the `th` tag for that column.

You can then set the config for that column on the properties on the hr tag, for example to set the formatter for that column to html you would:

```html
<th tabulator-formatter="html"></th>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply, however I can not get this to work. See this jsfiddle. Omitting the title just creates an extra column.

https://jsfiddle.net/2uypqbed/3/

Comment: sorry i misunderstood that you were importing from an HTML table, in that case you don't want to have any column definitions, simply update your HR tags, i have updated my example

Comment: Hi @oli-folkerd, thank you for your answer. I've found a bug when defining multiple columns with no title, I've filed a bug, https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3061

Comment: There isnt a bug with that, that is a limitation of that approach, i have explained more in your issue

Answer (score 0):

Add

> field:"preview",

to your column definition for the 2nd field.

Though I don't know why it then creates a 4th column with the preview data, but it does create the 2nd column as I think you want ....

Comment: This indeed shows the column as I want, but as you correctly point out, the same column is shown as a fourth column https://jsfiddle.net/bv3zhpjs/